# Facebook Oembed Response Not returning Json

Tags: c#, facebook, oembed

I'm trying to make a Get request to Facebook's Oembed endpoint from server side.  When I just go to the URL in my browser it works (click this link: https://www.facebook.com/plugins/video/oembed.json/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Ffacebook%2Fvideos%2F10153231379946729%2F)

However, when making the call from the server side, response isn't a json object.

```
      static void Main(string[] args)
       {
           string uri2 = "https://www.facebook.com/plugins/video/oembed.json/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Ffacebook%2Fvideos%2F10153231379946729%2F";

           CreateLinkRequest call2 = new CreateLinkRequest();
           call2 = Get<CreateLinkRequest>(uri2);
           Console.ReadLine();
       }


       public static T Get<T>(string uri)
       {
           HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
           request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate;

           using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
           using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
           using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
           {
               string json = reader.ReadToEnd();
               Object result = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<T>(json);
               return (T)result;
           }
       }
   }

   public class CreateLinkRequest
   {

       public string provider_name { get; set; }
       public string author_name { get; set; }
       public string width { get; set; }
       public string author_url { get; set; }
       public string title { get; set; }
       public string type { get; set; }
       public string version { get; set; }
       public string thumbnail_width { get; set; }
       public string provider_url { get; set; }
       public string thumbnail_height { get; set; }
       public string html { get; set; }
       public int height { get; set; }
       public string thumbnail_url { get; set; }
   }
```

Comment: I get their “upgrade your browser” page, when I make a “naked” server-side request for that URL. Try adding a User-Agent header to your request that matches a current browser.

Comment: Figured it out, you were on the right path but I had to set the UserAgent and Refer properties on the HttPWebRequest.  I guess facebook wants to make sure you're not a bot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, you were on the right path but I had to set the UserAgent and Refer properties on the HttPWebRequest. I guess facebook wants to make sure you're not a bot

```
      public static T Get<T>(string uri)
       {
           HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
            request.UserAgent = "Mozilla / 5.0(Windows; U; WindowsNT 5.1; en - US; rv1.8.1.6) Gecko / 20070725 Firefox / 2.0.0.6";
            request.Referer = "http://www.google.com";
           request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate;

           using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
           using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
           using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
           {
               string json = reader.ReadToEnd();
               Object result = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<T>(json);
               return (T)result;
           }
       }
   }
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61902621/facebook-oembed-returns-unsupported-browser-page-for-httprequestmessage-with-use